# Why does my if-chain not stop?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I was running a program with my students today and we came to a method that asked them to create conditional statements that prompts the user on the day of week after an input of 1 - 7 which correspond to Sunday to Saturday.

A student came up with the code below which prints out "Thursday", but it also prints out the else statement.  I cannot figure out why it does not stop at d == 5. But when I changed the method to return a String and had each if statement return a String like "Sunday" it worked.  The code is below.  Why does the program not stop for the void method, but stop for the String method?

```
public static void dayOfWeek(int d) //This did not stop at d == 5.
    {
        if (d == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Sunday");
        }
        if (d == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Monday");
        }
        if (d == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Tuesday");
        }
        if (d == 4)
        {
            System.out.println("Wednesday");
        }
        if (d == 5)
        {
            System.out.println("Thursday");
        }
        if (d == 6)
        {
            System.out.println("Friday");
        }
        if (d == 7)
        {
            System.out.println("Saturday");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Oops! Number must be between 1 and 7");
        }
    }

public static String dayOfWeek(int d) //This worked at d == 5.
{
    if (d == 1)
    {
        return "Sunday";
    }
    if (d == 2)
    {
        return "Monday";
    }
    if (d == 3)
    {
        return "Tuesday";
    }
    if (d == 4)
    {
        return "Wednesday";
    }
    if (d == 5)
    {
        return "Thursday";
    }
    if (d == 6)
    {
        return "Friday";
    }
    if (d == 7)
    {
        return "Saturday";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Oops! Number must be between 1 and 7";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it? Why do you think that `else` belongs to the other `if`s as well and not just the last one?

Comment: There is no 'if chain' in this case. You have a bunch of consecutive but independent ifs and finally and if with an else, which belongs to that final if alone. So what happens is, the first if is run, no matter what happens the second one is run, no matter what happens the third one is run, and so on till the last one which has an else and a non-matching condition so you see the output of the else.

Comment: The second example only works because of the `return` statement not because of the method returning `String`. but as @Tom has stated the `else` block is only associated with the last `if` statement.

Comment: The construct you're probably thinking of is `if { ... } else if {... } else` etc. But that's not what you have.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that there is a difference between an `else if` and and `if` when used in consecutive conditionals. In your situation

```
if (a) { .. }
if (b) { .. }
else { .. }
```

the `if (a)` conditional is not related in any way to `if (b)`. Both conditions are evaluated independently and their body executed accordingly. So the `else` condition is attached to the second conditional only and will be executed when `b` is `false` regardless of what's been executed before.

In any case you'd better use a `String[]` for that situation, eg:

```
private static final String[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday" ... };

public static String dayOfWeek(int d) {
  if (d >= 1 && d <= 7)
    return days[d-1];
  else
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Day of the week out of bounds!");
}
```

Comment: with a check against `days.length`, this would work when it's inevitably modified to return the days of the 10 day French Republican Calendar week.